# I've got access to database but not database name, can I find it out somehow?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to submit some data into database using php,sql for school homework.

I think know how to do it, but all the data about the connection I recieved are:

- Address of database
- username and password
- Information about table where I am supposed to insert my data.

If I want to connect to database using `mysqli_connect($address,$username,$password,$dbName)`
I can't, because I dont know $dbName.

Is this part of the homework that I have to somehow find out the name of the db(is it possible?) Or is there an error in assignment?

I would be very glad if you could help me out. I've been trying to wrap my head around it for solid two hours, but without success.
Thanks!

Comment: you could fire `show databases` to list all of them

Comment: If you're not sure about the requirement for an assignment, you should ask your teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
show databases
```

will give you a table with a list of databases in your database